# Builder pattern for methods with exception handling

Tags: java, oop, exception

I have a couple of methods that look like this:

```
public void do(A a, B b);

public void do(A A, C c);

public void do(D d, A a);

public void do(D d, E e, X x, F f, Optional<A> a);
```

And so on, there are about a dozens method that does basically the same but with varying parameters.

Now I thought about using a builder pattern that would allow me to use the functionality like this:

```
withA(a).withB(b).withX(x).do();
```

However, the problem is that one of the dozens of methods throws an exception. If I use a builder pattern, then `do()` will have to throw this exception and therefore all clients will have to handle it. In my opinion, this sounds like a problem.

My question:

- Is this a problem?
- If it is, how can it be avoided?

Comment: why does it throw this exception? ist it a validation? the you nay extract that validationa and require only valid parameters to be passed...

Comment: I'm throwing the exception when the calculation in do turns out to be not as expected.

Comment: That means you're doing *business logic* in a *setter*. This is a violation of the *Single Responsibility Pattern*

Comment: [This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/241309/builder-pattern-when-to-fail) is related/helpful.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Yes, but that's something that is not possible to change right now.

Comment: It's your decision what has priority: *clean code* or *dirty workaround* to enable your fluent API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is a problem.

You may:

1. Catch the exception if you know how to handle it and if the field to be set is optional.
2. But if the exception gets thrown when you try to set a mandatory field then it means something is wrong and the whole operation should fail.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the simple "turn it into a RuntimeException" solution.

Simply have a try/catch; and within catch, create a new RuntimeException to wrap around the checked exception - and rethrow that. ANd document in javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

You could change context when you use as a parameter the type that happens to cause the exception.

Mind you that this is not the brightest idea, and probably shouldn't be encouraged.

Sample Builders:

```
class ParamA{}    
class ParamB{}

class Builder {

    // ... More Stuff ...

    public Builder with(ParamA p){
        // x happens here
        return this;
    }

    public BuilderB with(ParamB p){
        // y happens here
        return new BuilderB(this);
    }

    public void doWork(){
        System.out.println("I did my stuff");
    }
}


class BuilderB{
    private BuilderB(){}

    public BuilderB(Builder b) {
        //Initialize with stuff from b
    }

    public BuilderB with(ParamB p){
        // y happens here
        return this;
    }
    public BuilderB with(ParamA p){
        // x happens here
        return this;
    }

    public void doStuff() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("poof");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
void example() {

    ParamA a = new ParamA();
    ParamB b = new ParamB();

    // doWork in builder doesn't throw, we're good
    new Builder().with(a).with(a).doWork();

    try {
        // stuff in BuilderB trhows, surround w/ try catch
        c.new Builder().with(a).with(b).doStuff();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception goes " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```